# Minimizing a log-determinant divergence based function

Tags: optimization, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

For a problem of the form $X\approx S$, where $X$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric but not always PD matrix, and $S$ its approximate, I am trying to minimize the log-determinant divergence between $X$ and $S$, that is:
$$\min_S \text{Tr}(XS^{-1}) - \log\det(XS^{-1})$$

However, the corresponding algorithm I developed and implemented only works with synthetic data. Real data does not give the expected results.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

I will appreciate any help from you. Thank you.

Comment: is $S$ positive definite?

Comment: Not always, X is a symmetric similarity matrix and is positive semi-definite (PSD), so the idea is to find another approximate S, which is PSD.

Comment: I believe this is a difficult non-convex optimization problem;. Specifically, a Nonlinear SDP (Semidefinite Programming problem)

Comment: However, if you're willing to change the objective to be some kind of norm of $S - X$, this would become a Linear SDP, which is convex, and relatively easy to solve, unless the matrices are too large. For instance, minimize the Frobenius norm of $S - X$, subject to S being PSD. Trivial to input into a a convex optimization tool such as CVX, CVXPY, CVXR, or YALMIP.;  In CVX, it would be:  cvx_begin, variable S(n,n) semidefinite;. minimize(norm(S-X,'fro')), cvx_end

Comment: Thank you @MarkL.Stone, I really appreciate your comment. The idea is that the space of any PSD matrix is not Euclidean, so I want to avoid using an Euclidean measure for data that lie on a manifold. I have already developed an iterative algorithm to solve the problem, but the issue is with strange results. It works with different synthetic data and fails with real data. Both data generated with the same protocol. My X is a PSD similarity matrix, and S is a low rank approximation of it.

Comment: Is there a constraint I can use to force S to be a DSP?

Comment: Yes, it's called a semidefinite constraint. Or you can impose constraint $S = WW^T$. W could be square, or if you want S to be  a low-rank matrix, make W an n by m matrix, where m < n. That will be an unpleasant non-convex quadratic constraint.  Given your problem as you stated it is non-convex, you might be finding a local minimum, or maybe a saddle point, which could be much worse than the global optimum. You could solve the PSD-constrained Frobenius norm minimization problem to get a starting value for the iteration of the algorithm for the non-convex problem.

Comment: Thank you @MarkL.Stone, I will try your idea. For the model I posted, I have invested time on the model and really I want to at least understand what is the issue and learn something new from it. The logdet divergence involves logarithm which may raise issues with values between [0, 1] like the case of X (symmetric similarity), but this only counts for the objective function. Even when we get negative values we still can minimizes until we get it smaller.

Comment: `logdet` is a very difficult thing to deal with in optimization when its argument is not positive definite.

Comment: I used some trick to force X to be PD, and S at each iteration, but still have only good results with any synthetic data I use. With real data it fails.